# Google SQL query (MySQL)

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Sorry, newbie in SQL. I have such table in Google Cloud SQL (MySql). 
How can I get time difference between surrounding rows like 164 and 165?
I want to get time period (downtime) when no one sencor worked with the condition that downtime more 20 minutes.

```
autoID | Datetime         | Number_of_sensor
163   | 2020-04-06 13:46:42 | C3
164   | 2020-04-06 13:46:45 | C4
165   | 2020-04-06 15:10:48 | C3
166   | 2020-04-06 15:46:48 | C4
```

I tried something but cann't get result.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use something called [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html), which are only available on MySQL after version 8.0

Google Cloud SQL for MySQL is only up version 5.7 for now.

However if you use Postgres that will be able to run as a Window Function SQL Query.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I will try! I'm already exhausted in finding a solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native TIMESTAMPDIFF() function, using the values from 2 tables offset by 1 as arguments, and join those 2 tables. This will work with MySQL 5.7 which is used on Google Cloud SQL.

```
SELECT a.autoID, a.Datetime , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,a.Datetime,COALESCE(b.Datetime,0)) as downtime 
FROM test a
LEFT JOIN test b on a.autoID=b.autoID-1
HAVING downtime > 20;
```

Comment: In this case I recommend "Accepting" the answer, by clicking the checkmark.